# How can the code be made more compact with more conditions?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a button that updates the data depending on which page you are on.  But due to the large number of conditions, the code is too stretched.

Can it be made somehow more compact?

```
 refresh() {
    this.store$.dispatch(setLoadingSpinner({ status: true }));
    this.store$.dispatch(loadCountNotifications());
    this.store$.dispatch(loadCountPostsIsTrue());

    if (this.route.routerState.snapshot.url.includes('/notifications')) {
      this.store$.dispatch(loadNotifications({ page: 1, pageSize: 10 }));
    }

    if (this.route.routerState.snapshot.url.includes('/organizations')) {
      this.store$.dispatch(loadOrgs());
    }

    if (this.route.routerState.snapshot.url.includes('/users')) {
      this.store$.dispatch(loadUsers());
    }

    if (
      this.route.routerState.snapshot.url.includes('/requests') &&
      !this.route.routerState.snapshot.url.includes('/requests/n/') &&
      !this.route.routerState.snapshot.url.includes('/requests/post/')
    ) {
      this.store$.dispatch(loadOrgs());
    }

    if (this.route.routerState.snapshot.url.includes('/requests/n/')) {
      this.store$.dispatch(loadPosts());
    }

    if (
      this.route.routerState.snapshot.url.includes('/requests/post/') ||
      this.route.routerState.snapshot.url.includes('/my_requests/n/')
    ) {
      this.store$.dispatch(loadPosts());
      this.store$.dispatch(loadComments());
    }
    
    if (
      this.route.routerState.snapshot.url.includes('/my_requests') &&
      !this.route.routerState.snapshot.url.includes('/my_requests/n/')
    ) {
      this.store$.dispatch(loadPosts());
    }
  }
```

Comment: Checking the load conditions inside the dispatched methods might make it more readible. Methods can decide weather they sould be loaded or not.

Answer (score 0):

first of all store the url in variable:

`const url = this.route.routerState.snapshot.url`
second of all, you can use `switch` build in function like this:

```
const url = this.route.routerState.snapshot.url
switch(true) {
   case url.includes('/notifications'): 
      this.store$.dispatch(loadNotifications({ page: 1, pageSize: 10 }));
   case url.includes('/organizations'): 
      this.store$.dispatch(loadOrgs());
   case url.includes('/users'): 
      this.store$.dispatch(loadUsers());
}
```

I think it's cleaner :)

Comment: add the `break`  to your switch

Comment: @Eliseo there are no `else` in original code, so `break` here will change the logic

Comment: exactly why I didn't add it :)

Comment: True, apologies